# Is a non biconnected outerplanar graph just a tree?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs, graph-connectivity

I'm having a difficult time visualising it...

If we make it non biconnected, thus removing all vertices which give us alternative paths from 1 vertex to another, and with all vertices belonging to the outer face of the graph, wouldn't this be a tree?

Comment: It is poor practice to rely solely on the title to pose a problem, both because the title is very limited in the space it allows you and because the "jump" from title to body of the Question invites confusion on the Reader's part.  So use the expanded space allowed in the body to set up the problem (some definition or link for "outer planar", etc.) and state the goal (prove a graph with certain properties is a tree).  Brevity invites doubts such as whether you'd accept that a graph which is not connected is not a tree, etc.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a counterexample from the Wikipedia page of ”biconnected graph”.

[image: Non biconnected outerplanar]

Answer (score 1):

No. The key thing is in order for a graph not to be biconnected, there only needs to be *some* pair of vertices where there is no path avoiding a certain intermediate vertex. (You seem to be thinking this needs to be true for *every* pair.)

So one way to be outerplanar but not biconnected (without being a tree) is to take a figure-eight type graph formed by identifying two cycles at a single vertex. It is not biconnected because removing that vertex disconnects the graph. Although any pair of vertices on the same cycle have two disjoint paths between them, for any two vertices on opposite sides the path needs to go though the central vertex.